# wkhtmltopdf and adobe font metrics

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, dompdf

I used to work with DOMPDF to generate my PDF. But I switched to wkhtmltopdf to improve performance.

I am stuck with fonts representation. In DOMPDF, the library uses adobe font metrics and the rendering is really nice. How can I use adobe font metrics with wkhtmltopdf?

Answer (score 0):

> I think adobe font metrics not support in wkhtmltopdf.  if you
>   continue to do the pdf in wkhtml then use it SVG font format. It's
>   work fine.

Comment: How can i use SVG font format with wkhtmltopdf please ?